# Java streams replace nested for loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a nested for loop I'd like to replace with streams, but I can't figure out how to, if it's possible. The basic loop is below

```
for (Object outer : owner.getOuterList())
    for (Object inner : owner.getInnerList())
        if (cond(outer, inner))
            func(outer, inner);
        else
            moo(outer, inner);
```

The only solution I've been able to arrive is basically looks exactly the same using `forEach` instead of the loops. `flatMap` seems applicable but I can't figure out how to get both lists.

Comment: If these are purely imperative things, then yes, it's going to look exactly the same.  Streams are for transforming and filtering and getting out _new_ elements, generally.

Comment: Yep, @Pillar link is basically what you need. `.flatMap(outer -> owner.getInnerList().stream().map(inner -> new Object[] { outer, inner }))` The issue is always having a Tuple class for holding both `inner` and `outer`. Here since they are both `Object`, we could abuse an array... All in all: keep the `for` loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks Pillar and Tunaki. Kind of sucks that there isn't a significantly cleaner way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the inner loop body

```
if (cond(outer, inner))
    func(outer, inner);
else
    moo(outer, inner);
```

has no counterpart in the Stream API and remains a single opaque action for most thinkable solutions, so the simplest solution is to express it as a `Consumer` which you invoke using a nested `forEach`, which offers no benefit to the nested `for` loop you already have.

If you want to enforce a `flatMap` based solution, you can do the following:

```
owner.getOuterList().stream().flatMap(
    outer -> owner.getInnerList().stream().<Runnable>map(
        inner -> cond(outer, inner)? () -> func(outer, inner): () -> moo(outer, inner))
).forEach(Runnable::run);
```

It doesn’t need a Pair/Tuple type for mapping to `[outer,inner]` as the functions themself are capable of capturing these values. Note that this will evaluate the condition in the inner stream processing but the actual invocation of either `func` or `moo` will happen in the outer stream processing. You can enforce processing everything within the outer stream with

```
owner.getOuterList().stream().flatMap(
    outer -> owner.getInnerList().stream().<Runnable>map(
        inner -> () -> { if(cond(outer,inner)) func(outer,inner); else moo(outer,inner); })
).forEach(Runnable::run);
```

which, as said, treats your original inner loop’s body like an opaque action.

I think, it’s clear that neither is a real win over the original nested `for` loop here.